# How does Maven resolve a version of a plugin to execute?

Tags: maven, command-line-interface, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

There are several downloaded versions of `maven-dependency-plugin` in my local repository. In a metadata file placed in `org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/` versions from `2.0-alpha-1` to `2.10` are listed.
Version `2.10` is set as `release` and `latest`.

Despite that when `dependency:get` is executed as a standalone goal from CLI Maven uses the version `2.1`. This is the lesser downloaded version of the plugin. Moreover if the version is removed from the local repository Maven downloads it again.

Maven 3.0.4 is used.

**Question**: How does Maven determine which version of a plugin will be used when it's not specified explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing a plugin' goal from command line without explicitely providing its version, Maven will use its latest one, except for plugins declared as part of the [super pom](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html), that is, the [implic parent pom](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom.html) of all Maven builds.

In this case, the `maven-dependency-plugin` is part of the little (and decreasing) set of plugins declared in the parent pom, for which version `2.1` is [specified](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.5/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html) till Maven version `3.0.5`, from that version on then it has been updated to version `2.8`.

Additionally, Maven resolves plugin versions via the [default lifecycle bindings](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/default-bindings.html), depending on the `packaging` option declared in a `pom.xml` file (not applicable for command line executions though).

Comment: As alway define the plugin versions via pluginManagement yourself and don't rely on super pom etc.